# Custom controller in Umbraco is not getting hit at the breakpoint

Tags: controller, umbraco

I am trying to implement a custom controller in an installation of Umbraco 7.3.0 and the breakpoint is just not getting hit.
I have followed the instructions on the Our Umbraco site for custom controllers (https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers), but no matter what I do it isn't getting hit.

My controller code is:-

```
public class GovernorPortalController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GovernorPortalChildPage(RenderModel model)
    {
        return base.Index(model);
    }
}
```

Where 
GovernorPortal = Document Type alias for this template

GovernorPortalChildPage = Template alias

The view is getting rendered, but I want to interact with it before it does so I can pass a model. I have even tried adding a route to RegisterRoutes but all this does is render a blank view with absolutely no html. Is there some hidden tweak in a config file that needs setting to get custom controllers to work?

Comment: Try overriding index instead of using the template name.

Comment: Thanks, overriding the Index method worked perfectly, don't know how I missed that. Fresh pair of eyes at the problem.